# Integrating Crystal Report with Spring Framework - JSP

Tags: spring, jsp, crystal-reports

I am integrating my Crystal Report code with Spring Framework.
Initially I had developed simple web application with only jsps (without spring feature) and CRystal Reports are rendering properly. I had tested it with parameters and DB connection Also.

Now I am trying to integrate it with Spring framework. I did all necessary set-up.
Reports are rendering properly, with parameters and DB connection. But when I click on subreport link I am getting error.

> "The viewer is unable to connect with the CrystalReportViewerServlet
>   that handles asynchronous requests. Please ensure that the Servlet and
>   Servlet-Mapping have been properly declared in the application's
>   web.xml file."

Also, images on reports are not displaying (showing cross).I tried to search on different forums but no luck.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">     <display-name>CRWeb1</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
<param-name>crystal_image_uri</param-name>
<param-value>/reports/crystalreportviewers</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
<param-name>crystal_image_use_relative</param-name>
<param-value>reports</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>reports</display-name>
<servlet-name>reports</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet- class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>reports</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <display-name>reports</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.crystaldecisions.report.web.viewer.CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CrystalReportViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CrystalReportViewerHandler</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks,
Sarika